# Is there a way to grab the last item of a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a DataFrame

```
data = {'Column 1':     [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
        'Column 2':     [ 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
        'Column 3':     [ 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 1, 2, 7, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I want to grab row 2, 5, 6 and 10 because these are the last row for each value in Column 1. Let's say Column 1 is an ID and Column 2 indicates the number of that ID. I need it to pick the maximum number in Column 2 for each number in Column 1 and keep Column 3 without changing Column 2 and 3 pairs.

So I go from

```
1  1  1
1  2  2
2  1  1
2  2  4
2  3  3
3  1  6
4  1  1
4  2  2
4  3  7
4  4  5
```

to

```
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  1  6
4  4  5
```

If I do

```
df.groupby(['Column 1']).max()
```

I do not get what I want, because it will max both column 2 and 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `groupby`/`tail`

```
df.groupby('Column 1').tail(1)

   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
1         1         2         2
4         2         3         3
5         3         1         6
9         4         4         5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Groupby.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
In [198]: df.groupby('Column 1', as_index=False).nth([-1])    
Out[198]: 
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
1         1         2         2
4         2         3         3
5         3         1         6
9         4         4         5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `drop_duplicates`

```
df_final = df.drop_duplicates('Column 1', keep='last')

Out[9]:
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
1         1         2         2
4         2         3         3
5         3         1         6
9         4         4         5
```

Answer (score 1):

if your Dataframe is ordered we don't need `groupby`, we can perform a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)

```
df_filtered = df.loc[~df['Column 2'].lt(df['Column 2'].shift(-1))]
print(df_filtered)
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
1         1         2         2
4         2         3         3
5         3         1         6
9         4         4         5
```